# Not able to pass variables to some other method within the class

Tags: python, airflow

Hi team through some API call i am generating some values through a method and i wanted to use those variables through out the class but i am not able to pass those to some other method within the class can you please help

I tried global thing didn't work

```
class myClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        p_id, e_id, env, trigger_type = self.helper()

    def helper(self, **kwargs):
        p_id = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('project_id')
        e_id = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('exec_id')
        env = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('env')
        trigger_type = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('target')

        return p_id, e_id, env, trigger_type

    def checkHostname(self, **kwargs):

       print("<<<>>>>>>>><<<<",self.p_id)

A = myClass()


task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='printing', provide_context=True, python_callable=A.checkHostname, dag=dag, )  

task1
```

when i call the A.checkHostname it should print the values generated from previous method

Comment: `self.p_id, self.e_id ... = ...`

Answer (score 2):

Instance variables need to refer to the instance: that's what `self` is for. By not using it inside your `__init__`, you are creating variables that effectively cannot be seen from outside the scope of `__init__` itself.

```py
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.p_id, self.e_id, self.env, self.trigger_type = self.helper()
# ...
```